# Function for defining and printing all the elements of a matrix

Tags: c, function, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops

I'm studying functions in C, and I wanted to create a function to set all the elements of a matrix with the same value, and then print the matrix with another function. Is it possible? This is the code I wrote[EDITED]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define x 79
#define y 24

int def_matrice(int matrice[y][x], int valore);
int print_matrice(int matrice[y][x]);

int main()
{
    int  i = 0, j = 0, matrice[y][x];

    for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            matrice[i][j] = 32;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", matrice[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    def_matrice(matrice[y][x], 89);
    print_matrice(matrice[y][x]);

    return 0;
}

int def_matrice(int matrice[y][x], int valore)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            matrice[i][j] = valore;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int print_matrice(int matrice[y][x])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", matrice[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile, I get the following errors[EDITED]:

```
|30|error: passing argument 1 of 'def_matrice' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
|6|note: expected 'int (*)[79]' but argument is of type 'int'|
|31|error: passing argument 1 of 'print_matrice' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
|7|note: expected 'int (*)[79]' but argument is of type 'int'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Where did you see this syntax: `int matrice[int y][int x]`?

Comment: nowhere, I tried because in my book there aren't example of this type, Just simple arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your prototypes (at function declaratio and function definition):

```
int def_matrice(int matrice[y][x], int valore)
int print_matrice(int matrice[y][x])
```

Then fix your function calls:

```
def_matrice(griglia, 89);
print_matrice(griglia);
```

Then you need declarations for `i` and `j` in `def_matrice` and in `print_matrice`.

Then `def_matrice` and `print_matrice` have parameter names `matrice` but the name `griglia` is used in the functions.

Comment: So def_matrice and print_matrice will always work on a single matrix that have the same name of their parameter?

Comment: @Granpasso you declare a parameter name `matrice` in your function but you never use it. Instead you use `griglia` which is not in the scope of the function.

Comment: I edited it but I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Granpasso you should not edit your question and modify it when you see answers otherwise answers will no longer make sense for a reader. Second you still have errors because you didn't address the second point I covered in my answer. Now regarding your comment your `griglia` array was declared in `main`, so it is not visible in the other functions: you were using `griglia` in `def_matrice` body where it is not visible.